# Django - Rosetta : Ignore .mo files issue

Tags: python, django, git, django-rosetta

I'm using:

- Rosetta - 0.7.2
- Django - 1.4.3

What I'm trying:

- Ignore the `.mo` files but keep tracking `.po`

I've been using Rosetta and Django for the past year and never had an issue like this. I want to ignore `.mo` files, but not the `.po` ones. The `.mo` files represent the compiled value of the `.po` files. My goal is when I change any translation in develop, I want git to ignore the `.mo` files.

I have 9 languages in the actual project, I tried to add in my `.gitignore` file this:

```
*.mo
```

but it doesn't work. I've also tried:

```
myapp/locale/*/LC_MESSAGES/*.mo
```

but didn't work neither, I tried:

```
myapp/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/*.mo
myapp/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/*.mo
myapp/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/*.mo
myapp/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/*.mo
```

This works but I don't want to add each language path to the `.mo` files because in the future I'd probably need to add more languages and want to avoid modifying the .gitignore file each time.

Any ideas about how to achieve this ?

**More info:**

- I've removed/discarded changes each time I tried something
- I had multiple .gitignore files, but now it's only one
- As far as I know the rule `*.mo` in .gitignore should ignore all files, no matter the path, same as `.*pyc` ignore all compiled files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once I had same issue to remove `*.sql` files from git, and my problem was that the `.sql` file was in the repository, so although I delete in develop and add `*.sql` to gitignore, git never ignore them because they were already in the repository.

So I recommend you to delete all `.mo` files **from repository**, and then add `*.mo` to your `.gitignore` file and upload it, then it should ignore all your `.mo` files.

Answer (score 1):

Steps are

1. `git rm -r --cached .` which will ignore already tracked files and which are in your `.gitignore`
2. git add .
3. git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"